# Solaris and smf: how to do a rc.local shutdown with smf?

Tags: solaris, smf

With the old good SystemV scripts, if I want something before shutdown, I put a script like this in /etc/rc0.d/

```
K400rc.local.shutdown.sh
```

And I edit it and put my commands which I want to run before shutdown.
On linux with systemd I have created a "manifest" like this

```
vim /lib/systemd/system/rc-local-shutdown.service

[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local.shutdown Compatibility
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.local.shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
After=rc-local.service basic.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local.shutdown
StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

Works very good..and before shutdown I can put my commands.
The question is..someone know how to do a manifest like this with Solaris smf?
I know how to do a rc.local but not to do a rc.local.shutdown manifest.
Someone know?

Comment: [van Smoorenburg `rc` is not AT&T System 5, and the _actual_ AT&T Unix System 5 replaced `rc.local` with a new system](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/rc.local-is-history.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris `smf` is honoring legacy scripts so your `/etc/rc0.d/K400rc.local.shutdown.sh` will be executed at shutdown. The prefix `K40` and the suffix `.sh`are the only parts that matter, the remaining `0rc.local.shutdown` has no meaning for the OS.

Should you want to convert this task to a `smf` service, instead of thinking in term of shutdown and run levels, better to identify what your service will depend on (your service will stop after the selected service ends).

Then create a manifest with a no-op start `exec-method` and using your shutdown script as stop `exec-method`.